# Reportlab split text in two lines

Tags: python, python-2.7, reportlab

I am using table in report lab, and sometimes text in a column is wider than the width of column, and it overleaps the text in next column, is there a way to automatically split it into two lines if it is too long?

Comment: I found solution, I just needed to wrap text in <para> tag.

Comment: If you have answered your own question, you should give it as an answer below and choose it as the accepted answer. That way you can give yourself proper credit for figuring it out.

Answer (score 0):

I found solution, I just needed to wrap text in  tag.